# Javascript getting a substring with condition

Tags: javascript

Say a user inputs a string into the search box in my app such as `"yasin ullah&&khan"`

How do get this string in this format: `"yasin (ullah|khan)"` with JavaScript.

If the user does not enter `"&&"` in the search box, then I just want to get the normal text.

Comment: So you want to separate the words by `&&`

Comment: no just those two words attached to either sides of "&&" my string not .spliting the whole paragraphe

Comment: I can replace the "&&" with "|" sign simply but how do add the "()" sign boundaries around the words

Comment: `result = text.replace(/([a-z]+)&&([a-z]+)/gi, "($1|$2)");`.

Comment: working with english but i want it for urdu

var text = "یسین اللہ&&حان"
result = text.replace(/([a-z]+)&&([a-z]+)/gi, "($1|$2)");
Output:یسین اللہ&&حان"

Comment: `result = text.replace(/(\S+)&&(\S+)/gi, "($1|$2)");`. (where `\S` means any character that isn't a space character).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
var name = "yasin ullah&&khan",
  re = /^(.+ )(.+?)&&(.+)$/;
console.log(name.replace(re, "$1($2|$3)"));
name = "یاسین الله&&خان"
console.log(name.replace(re, "$1($2|$3)"));
```

Comment: Thanks for adding snippet :) I have typed my answer via my mobile phone and I haven't access to the code tools of `stackoverflow` editor.